# How to block an embedded frame from loading when it is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This frame is hidden when i haven't selected annything with angular , how can i stop it from loading ? Because my console is now spammed with errors because it's loading when nothing is selected yet..

```
 <object data="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=AIzaSyDlcgqT3WT7WlU3R-636TpPEaVEHwqK6Ls&q={{selectedSong.artist.country.name}}" 
                                      width="600" height="400">
                        <embed ng-src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=AIzaSyDlcgqT3WT7WlU3R-636TpPEaVEHwqK6Ls&q={{selectedSong.artist.country.name}}" 
                                        width="600" height="400"></embed>
                                 Error: De map kon niet worden geladen
                        </object>
```

Comment: Hidden elements will still be loaded.  Have you considered creating the frame on demand?

Comment: I am now using an   ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)"  on it but i have a panel where i click wich divs are shown , can I put a method in this panel or something that makes it only load when clicked?